# Angular2 Service call Model Method

Tags: javascript, angular, service, model

I'm new to angular2 so I will try to make this question as clear as possible. I want to have a method in my model that I can call from my service. Right now I have it trying to replace the name.

Here is my model

```
    export class Secret {

    public name: string;

   constructor (
    public id: number,
    public type: string,
    public visible_data: any,
    public secrets?: any,
    public group_id?: number,
    public group_name?: string
   ) {
    this.name = this.myName();
   }

  public myName(): string {
   return this.name = "whaddup"
 }
```

}

and my service method

```
 /*
 * get secrets
*/
public getSecrets(): Promise<Secret[]> {
let tempArray = [];

return this.sdk.list_secrets()
  .then((resp) => {

    resp.map((item) => {

      tempArray.push({
        id: item.id,
        name: this.secret.myName(),
        type: item.type,
        visible_data: {
          "username": item.data
        }
      }); // end push

    });

    return tempArray;
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
  });
}
```

`list.component.ts` code:

```
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {

 public constantArray: Secret[];
 private secrets: Secret[];
 private secret: Secret;

  constructor(private secretService: SecretService) { }

public ngOnInit() {
  this.getSecrets();
}

public getSecrets() {
 this.secretService.getSecrets()
   .then((data) => {

     this.secrets = data;
     this.constantArray = data;

   });
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
tempArray.push({
    id: item.id,
    name: this.secret.myName(),
    type: item.type,
    visible_data: {
      "username": item.data
    }); // end push
```

You should do

```
tempArray.push(new Secret(item.id, ...));
```

Reason: in your original code, the object pushed to array are plain old javascript object and they are not typescript objects. The 'new ...' will create a real typescript class object.

Comment: I had to adjust my model to get the shape I wanted for my object but your solution worked! Thank you! 

`tempArray.push(
            new Secret(
              item.id,
              item.name,
              item.type,
              {
                "username":item.data.username
              },
              {
                "password":item.secret_through_set[0].data.password
              },
              item.secret_through_set[0].group)
          );`

Comment: Model for anyone who is interested 
`export class DataThrough {
  [propName: string]: any;
}

export class SecretThrough {
  [propName: string]: any;
}

export class Secret implements ISecret {

  constructor (
    public id: number,
    public name: string,
    public type: string,
    public visible_data: DataThrough,
    public secrets: SecretThrough,
    public group_id?: any,
    public group_name?: any
  ) { }
`

Comment: To be clear for anyone else that finds this question I didn't end up calling a method in my model, I adjusted the shape of my model and used your suggestion to push new Secret() instead of an object

Answer (score 0):

To work with angular2 service, you need to do two things. First of all you need to at the `@Injectable` annotation on top of your services.

If you want to inject services into each other, you need to provide them on your NgModule like this:

```
@NgModule({
    selector: 'my-app',
    providers: [NameService]
}):
```

If you want to inject the service into another service/component you can just leverage typescript and use constructor injection like this:

```
constructor(private secretService: SecretService) {}
```

Comment: Hi KwintenP, I appreciate the answer but I'm not trying to inject a service into another service.

Comment: Sorry, it cut off before I finished typing. I want to have a function in my model that I can call from my service. Is that something that is possible in angular2? I found something similar below (plnkr) but I can't get it to work in my app.

https://plnkr.co/edit/7lKHvArpayrMAzm5Xgk1?p=preview